# Remover timezone em requisição com node.js e express.js

Tags: node.js, express.js, timezone

Tenho uma `API` com `node.js` e `express.js`. No banco de dados os campos do tipo `datetime` estão salvos corretamente, porém na resposta de uma requição `GET` os campos de data vêm com 3 horas à mais devido ao fuso horário.

Estou fazendo esta requisição e consumindo o `json` em uma aplicação web e em um app `android nativo`.

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia resolver. Existe alguma possibilidade de remover o `timezone` na API, ou deveria configurar alguma coisa no banco de dados ou no servidor? Estou usando `MySQL`.

Exemplo:

```
**DB:** 2017-10-02 10:58:34

**JSON:** "2017-10-02T13:58:34.000Z"
```

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o exemplo dessa string que vem do GET? não tem fuso horário na string?

Comment: Atualizei com o exemplo.

Comment: Ok, mais duas perguntas: tens controlo sobre a criação da data do GET? qual é o timezone da data da BD?

Comment: Tenho sim. `@@system_time_zone: BRT`, `@@global.time_zone: SYSTEM`, `@@session.time_zone: SYSTEM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro usar uma biblioteca para a conversão. Por exemplo a extenção do moment.js para timzones, o [moment-timzone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Para fazer de maneira nativa podes usar UTC e somar a diferença para o teu horário, ou formatar a data com o `.toLocaleString('pt-br', {timezone: 'Brazil/brt'})`.  Os problemas que podem surgir são nos dias de mudança entre horário de verão e inverno que não tenho a certeza que o browser sabe essa informação.

Por exemplo tendo a data do JSON repara nos que podemos extrair:

```js
var json = "2017-10-02T13:58:34.000Z";
var date = new Date(json);

console.log('Dia:', date.getUTCDate(), 'Hora:', [date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMonth() + 1, date.getUTCMinutes()].join(':'));

console.log(date.toLocaleString('pt-br', {timezone: 'Brazil/brt'}));
```

Comment: Então o único jeito é tratando campo à campo mesmo? Não há uma maneira de remover ou alterar o timezone direto na aplicação, certo?

Comment: @FernandoZabin Sim, como não tens controlo sobre que país ou timezone o utilizador está, tens de gerir isso assim. O melhor talvez é fazer a conversão no momento de inserir.

Comment: Entendi. Fiz um teste rápido na aplicação web e formatando a data com o moment.js padrão, ele já corrige o fuso horário, não tinha observado antes. Acho que a solução para o app android seria adicionar uma conversão ao receber os dados também. Obrigado.

Comment: @FernandoZabin exato podias converter no ajax, assim o que chega ao servidor está normalizado